# Does Format Function Work In SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to use the format function to format a phone number in an SQl 2012 database but i keep on saying that format is not a recognized build in function? what do you think is wrong?

Comment: A google tells you it works from SQL 2012 onwards. So the issue must be that your compatability level is set to something earlier (usually because you upgraded the server from an older version at some point). Google "T-SQL compatability level"

Comment: Are you sure your database engine is 2012?  SELECT @@VERSION  will tell you